# I2C Scanner not working properly

Tags: i2c, mbed

First of all, please see my other question [HERE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/406736/how-to-read-data-from-this-sensor) as it is related (Any help with that is greatly appreciated too).

If you read through my other question, you will know that I am attempting to interface with a magnetic sensor IC, the [MLX90393](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/e/e/f/2/7/MLX90393-Datasheet-Melexis.PDF), on the [Sparkfun Breakout Board](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Sparkfun%20PDFs/SEN-14571_Web.pdf).

I have been having trouble reading the data from it, and I am confident the issue is in the code, not any of the hardware. The reason for this, is when I use the [ARDUINO EXAMPLE CODE](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity/MLX90393/blob/master/C/MLX90393.c) on GitHub, with the Arduino IDE (still using the STM32 Nucleo hardware), everything works and I can read the data from the sensor. However, when I attempted to convert that code over to mbed, I just get an error, and I am unable to extract the data.

I have now decided to see what would happen when trying to do a scan to find the address. Previoulsy, when doing an I2C scan in the mbed IDE, I got an ACK from every single address. The code I used was [HERE](https://os.mbed.com/users/Dominosus/code/I2C_scanner/docs/1301fb16e306/main_8cpp_source.html). When running this code, this is the response I got:

[image]

Please note I added an additional \n after "I2C device found at...." so that it didn't scroll across the screen. Please note I have tried it with Error ==0 and 1. When I use Error ==0 for mbed, I get 'No devices found'

This is almost an exact copy of the Arduino I2C scanner, which can be found [HERE](https://gist.github.com/tfeldmann/5411375). Looking through the 2 of them, they are basically exactly the same, and I cannot find the difference between them (bear in mind this is my first time working with I2C). When I run this code on the **same hardware** but via the Arduino IDE, this is what I get:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? What is the difference between doing this with the Arduino IDE and the mbed? I hope solving this issue may assist in solving the issue with my other question, but this is really getting frustrating. I have tried changing I2C pullups to different values and that had no effect either.

Comment: In your first code  you have "if (error == 1)" to decide if the I2C address is responding. Is this correct? In the Arduino code you use error==0.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen I have tried it with both 0 and 1. With 0 on the mbed, I get no devices found. I'll update the question

Comment: When I doubt the sanity of an I2C bus, I do two things: 1) pull out a logic analyzer (or scope) and watch the data on the pins. 2) Before initializing the bus, go nuclear, and dio-toggle the i2c clock line 9 times to flush the slave chips, and get them out of any incomplete state.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen but I have shown the I2C is working by using  the Arduino IDE and language on the same hardware. So this means there is nothing wrong with the hardware, or with the I2C lines. But these 2 code examples produce different results, even though when I look at them they are doing the same thing. I need someone who knows it better than I do (I am a complete beginner) to analyse it and find the difference because I have tried and Just cannot see why they are giving me different results

Comment: I agree there's something strange.  It is apparent that the different codes are interacting with the hardware differently.  Without viewing the lines with an analyzer, you are just guessing _why_ it's not working.  When dealing with busses, analyzers are required equipment.  They can be very cheap, or even made by yourself.  In a pinch, view the lines on a scope, and decode by hand.

Comment: @Curious - Hi, The comment from *Chris* is absolutely correct. When you get this kind of "cannot happen" issue with I2C, you need to start looking at the signals. You said: "*I2C is working by using the Arduino IDE and language on the same hardware. So this means there is nothing wrong with the hardware*". Actually that's not true. I understand why you believe it, but *some* hardware problems can be hidden by the *different timing* used by different code. IMHO you need to use a scope (not analyser) *first*, to view the I2C waveform shape, rise/fall times, voltage levels etc. Can you do that?

Comment: @SamGibson honestly, I would not know what to be looking for. I can stick a scope on it, but I would have no idea where to stop and look. Or what it meant if I saw a difference

Comment: @Curious - "*I would not know what to be looking for*" No problem, that's what we're here for :-) This type of "I2C scanner" does a start-address byte-stop sequence (very short). Change your code to scan *only* address 0x1 (which "responds" with the mbed code, and not with the Arduino code). Using a dual channel scope, capturing both signals, trigger the scope on SCL falling edge, adjust the timebase for that sequence to fill the screen horizontally, and adjust the vertical scale to fill the screen vertically (1V/div on both signals might be a starting point). Do that using both sets of code.

Comment: P.S. Depending on how this goes, we *might* be better moving to chat (if you agree) and come back to add any significant info into the question or comments here. Long comment threads get overwhelming fast...

Comment: @SamGibson yeah, may be best to move to chat. When I'm able to scope the lines I'll do it and post the results. How do I scan for only 0x01?

Comment: "*How do I scan for only 0x01?*" In both versions of the scanner source code, the easiest change is to allow the `for` loop to run only once - so change `for(address = 1; address < 127; address++ )` to `for(address = 1; address < 2; address++ )`. That line appears in both versions. I'll see if I can remember how to setup a chat room...

Comment: Chat room here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85973/discussion-on-question-by-curious-i2c-scanner-not-working-properly

Comment: @Curious post somewhere (like on github) the entier stack code for both arduino and your project.

Comment: @Damien it is a direct copy and paste from those links provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with the OP, this problem has been solved.

#### Short version:

- De-solder STM32F303K8 Nucleo-32 (NUCLEO-F303K8) board solder bridges SB16 and SB18 when using Mbed I2C functions.
- Use the "extended" 4-parameter Mbed `i2c.write()` call with the STM32F303K8 Nucleo-32 board.

#### Long version:

As I mentioned in comments (agreeing with *Chris Knudsen*), we needed to look at the signals. From my own experiences over the years, it can sometimes be important to *start* with a 'scope, since that can show important details about the shape and voltage levels of the signal waveforms, which cannot be seen with a logic analyser. Then after the analog waveforms have been verified, move on to using a logic analyser.

Using Arduino IDE and libraries for the STM32F303K8 Nucleo board, and running the [I2C scanner](https://gist.github.com/tfeldmann/5411375) just for I2C address 0x1 (which didn't exist on the bus), we saw this image of valid I2C activity (yellow = SDA, blue = SCL):

[image: Valid I2C using Arduino libraries, attempting to address non-existent IC device 0x01]

However running an equivalent [I2C scanner for Mbed](https://os.mbed.com/users/Dominosus/code/I2C_scanner/docs/1301fb16e306/main_8cpp_source.html), configured for the STM32F303K8 Nucleo board, we saw this on the I2C bus:

[image: Invalid I2C using Mbed libraries, attempting to address non-existent IC device 0x01]

This shows SDA stuck at approximately 2V, which is invalid i.e. not within the allowed range for logic 0 (typically < 0.2 Vdd) or logic 1 (typically > 0.8 Vdd). **This is a classic symptom of two output pins driving the same signal in opposite directions.**

Looking at the [STM32F303K8 Nucleo user guide (UM1956)](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/e3/0e/88/05/e8/74/43/a0/DM00231744.pdf/files/DM00231744.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00231744.pdf) we see that it actually connects the SCL and SDA pins to other pins, for some kind of compatibility with Arduino Nano analog input functionality.

[image: STM32 Nucleo-32 board solder bridges SB16 and SB18]

(Above edited from Table 8 in [STM32F303K8 Nucleo user guide (UM1956)](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/e3/0e/88/05/e8/74/43/a0/DM00231744.pdf/files/DM00231744.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00231744.pdf))

[image: Extract from STM32 Nucleo user guide schematic diagram]

(Above schematic extract from page 33 in [STM32F303K8 Nucleo user guide (UM1956)](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/e3/0e/88/05/e8/74/43/a0/DM00231744.pdf/files/DM00231744.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00231744.pdf))

That means that if the Mbed initialisation code didn't configure pins `PA5` and `PA6` as inputs without any pull-up/down resistors, then through those solder bridges, pins `PA5` and `PA6` could affect the I2C signals using pins `PB6` and `PB7`.

De-soldering those two solder bridges allowed I2C signals to be correctly seen, with the Mbed I2C scanner code:

[image: Valid I2C using Mbed libraries, attempting to address non-existent IC device 0x01]

During research, we found [this posting](https://os.mbed.com/questions/80738/Does-the-F303K8-support-mbed-i2c/) about using the STM32F303K8 Nucleo-32 (NUCLEO-F303K8) board with Mbed, which said:

> It looks like this device does not support the i2c.write(int data) method. i2c.write(int address, const char *data, int length); works.

Changing from [the original Mbed I2C scanner](https://os.mbed.com/users/Dominosus/code/I2C_scanner/docs/1301fb16e306/main_8cpp_source.html) (adapted from the standard Arduino I2C scanner) which used the sequence:

```
i2c.start();
error = i2c.write(address << 1);
i2c.stop();
```

to a [different Mbed I2C scanner](https://os.mbed.com/users/michaelVisimid/code/I2C_Bus_Scanner/file/545d57fc4eca/main.cpp/) using this different version of the `i2c.write()` function call instead:

```
returnCode = i2c.write((address << 1),&outByte,1,0);
```

then this different Mbed I2C scanner worked correctly.

This would be an area for deeper investigation of the Mbed source code and detailed I2C behaviour using a logic analyser, however we ran out of time. By documenting the process so far and what was found to work, I hope this is useful as a starting point for anyone else who wants to take the investigation further.